# How would I Write $n!$ in Product Notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, products

I have been having a difficult time writing $n!$ in capital $\prod$ notation.

Most of it is pretty easy but I can't seem to include $0!$ as a possible input since if I start the index $i$ at $0$, then the whole thing will be zero.

I have tried multiple other combinations of $i$ and $n$ but none of them have worked out. Any suggestions?

Comment: no because we have $0!=1$

Comment: it is \pi_{i=0}^n i!

Comment: The convention is that an empty product equals $1$.

Comment: $n!=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n i$ for all $n\in\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$.  Note the special case of $n=0$ is still satisfied since $\prod\limits_{i=1}^0 i$ is the ["empty product"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) which evaluates as $1$.

Comment: Yea I didn't know that "The convention is that an empty product equals 1"

Comment: For what it's worth, in a computer program you can do something like this: `factorial = 1; for (i = 2; i =< n; i++) { factorial *= i }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$n! = \prod_{i=1}^n i$$

Notice the [empty product convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) enables us to write it compactly to include $0!=1$.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know that existed.

Answer (score 4):

The [empty product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) is by convention defined as one:

$$\prod_{i=1}^0 a_i = 1$$

Thus,

$$n! =\prod_{i=1}^n i$$

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge1$, $$n!=1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots\cdot n=\prod_{i=1}^n i$$ and $0!=1$.